# Passing unset variables to functions

Tags: php, variables, exists

**My code:**

```
function Check($Variable, $DefaultValue) {
    if(isset($Variable) && $Variable != "" && $Variable != NULL) {
        return $Variable;
    }
    else {
        return $DefaultValue;
    }
}

$a = Check(@$foo, false);
$b = Check(@$bar, "Hello");

//$a now equals false because $foo was not set.
//$b now equals "Hello" because $bar was not set.
```

1. When a variable doesn't exist and is passed to the function (suppressing the error) what is actually passed?
2. Is there any undefined behaviour that this function could exhibit?
3. Is there a better way of wrapping the testing for variable existence and supplying a default value from a function?
4. What does `isset()` check under the hood when testing a variable?

---

**EDIT:**

The default value is there to be user defined. Sometimes it will be a number, sometimes a string.

Comment: You can pass a variable that isn't set if your function is looking for something by reference. Only down side is that it can't accept expressions, only variables. `function Check(&$Variable, $DefaultValue) { ... `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. NULL is passed, notice error is raised.
2. No, function sees only it's parameters (it doesn't care how it is being called)
3. You can specify default value easily - function func($mandatory, $optional = 'default value');
4. Isset withing a function on its parameters is pointless, because the parameters are already set in the functions signature.

Comment: is it necessary for the default-value parameters to be at the end of the parameter-list, like in C?

Comment: [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) returns false for variables with `null`: `$var = null; var_dump(isset($var));`

Comment: Thanks. The default value is there to be user defined. Sometimes it will be a number, sometimes a string.

Comment: @Dexter, it would be just illogic to do otherwise, because then you still would have to pass optional arguments if you don't want to but you have to pass some mandatory arguments that are further in the functions signature.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the variable to the method by reference by putting an & in front of it when declaring the function. Then you can just check if it set inside the function and not have to worry about suppressing warnings when passing the value that isn't set.

```
function Check(&$Variable, $DefaultValue) {
    if(isset($Variable) && $Variable != "" && $Variable != NULL) {
        return $Variable;
    }
    else {
        return $DefaultValue;
    }
}

$a = Check($foo, false);
$b = Check($bar, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `null` will be passed
2. There is no undefined behaviour in PHP AFAIK
3. Usually testing is done with `empty($var)`, e.g.: `Check(empty($foo) ? null : $foo)`, although depending on the circumstances `isset` may be more appropriate
4. What `isset` does is exactly [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) -- it tests if there is such a variable in scope and its value is not identical to `null`

Answer (score 2):

> When a variable doesn't exist and is
>   passed to the function (suppressing
>   the error) what is actually passed?

In this case, you try to read from a non-existent variable

So, you get `null` -- which is passed to the function.

> Is there any undefined behaviour that
>   this function could exhibit?

Not that I see -- except using the `@` operator is not quite a good practice.