# PHP switch - default if the variable is not set

Tags: php, switch-statement, isset

is there any way to simplify this code to avoid the need for an if to skip to the switch's default value?

I have a configuration table for different authentication methods for a http request, with an option not to set the value to default to a plain http request:

```
if(!isset($type)) {
    $type = "default";
}

switch ($type) {
   case "oauth":
       #instantinate an oauth class here
       break;
   case "http":
       #instantinate http auth class here
       break;
   default:
       #do an unprotected http request
       break;
}
```

I have no issue with the functionality, but I would like a cleaner solution to switch on an optional variable, is there any way to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you do not need to set it to "default" - you could put that code in a function and use syntax function funcName($type = "") which would set it to "" if a null value was passed ib.

Comment: Interesting catch there @andrewb  It's almost a little misleading in the code that the value if unset is set to the literal string 'default' and then execution in switch fall through to the 'default case'.  default:  is php syntax for an unmatched switch case.  you may as well set $type to "" or "barbecuebits".

Comment: Yeah that was sort of the issue. I just had to set $type to something as if it wasn't set, I'd end up with an error. To this day I'm not sure I know a better solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

```
switch ($type??'') {
    case "oauth":
        #instantinate an oauth class here
        break;
    case "http":
        #instantinate http auth class here
        break;
    default:
        #do an unprotected http request
        break;    
}
```

is enough on php >= 7

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to set the variable to "default". The default-case will be executed if the variable is not set or has any different value from all other defined cases. 
But remember: if the variable is not set and you use it in the switch, you will get a notice "Notice: Undefined variable". So if you don't want to disable notices you have to do the check if the variable is set.

Comment: I have failed to mention I need to avoid getting a Notice, so it seems there's no way to get around it without additional code, thanks.

Comment: While it may be frowned upon, you can suppress the Notice by placing `@` in front of the variable.

Comment: @musicin3d This is not a good practice. You should not use the `@` to supress errors etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573426/is-this-bad-practice-use-of-the-error-suppression-operator

Comment: See, I understand it's bad practice to suppress errors, and it's usually bad to suppress anything. But this is a Notice, akin to a linter warning... about something we're already handling (with `default:`). And IMO `switch(@ $var){...}` is MUCH more readable than wrapping the whole block in `if(isset($var)){...}`. I mean, the "variable not set" Notice is the only use for the `@` in this case, so you know exactly why it's there and it reduces indentation and clutter. This seems like one legitimate use case to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simplify it without getting a notice. Try the following:

```
if(!isset($type)) {
    #do an unprotected http request
}else{
    switch ($type) {
       case "oauth":
           #instantinate an oauth class here
           break;
       case "http":
           #instantinate http auth class here
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `default` case is a catch-all if none of the previous cases are found, so your check for whether the variable isset and assigning it to `"default"` is unnecessary.